# How to add 2nd floating label to input when using 1 div only in bootstrap 5

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, input, label, floating-labels

How can i add a 2nd floating label to the right input field? the problem now is that the 2nd label overlaps the first label in the 1st input field:

```
<div class="form-floating input-group">                         
    <input type="text" name="" class="form-control delete-from-date" value="" />
    <label for="floatingDateToDelete">startdate</label>
    <span class="input-group-text">till</span>                          
    <input type="text" name="" class="form-control delete-till-date" value="" />
    <label for="floatingDateToDelete">Enddate</label>   
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger delete-multiple-events" name="submit">Delete</button>               
</div>
```

here is a fiddle you can see the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/1uf0zv2d/6/

The floating label "Enddate" should occur in the right input field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `input`+`label` combo needs to be within its own `.form-floating` class. Having multiple inputs in the same div was causing that issue. Also, a placeholder is **required** on each input field.

I've moved the entire combo into a container that has `.input-group` on it. You can look at the changes here.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="form-floating">
      <input type="text" class="form-control delete-from-date" id="floatingDateToDelete1" placeholder="startdate" />
      <label for="floatingDateToDelete1">startdate</label>
    </div>
    <span class="input-group-text">till</span>
    <div class="form-floating">
      <input type="text" class="form-control delete-till-date" id="floatingDateToDelete2" placeholder="Enddate" />
      <label for="floatingDateToDelete2">Enddate</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger delete-multiple-events" name="submit">Delete</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you made my day @omar-siddiqui, it works like a charm. Thank you